# Derivative of a trace function

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, trace

Let $K$ be a Hermitian matrix, and $X$ be a positive one. What is the derivative of the trace function
  $$  \mbox{ Tr } X|e^{itK} - X|^3$$
with respect to $t$ at $t = 0$ ? There is a nice formula for this?

Comment: What $|\cdot|$ means?

Comment: I mean $|A| = (A^*A)^{1/2}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=e^{itK}-X$; then $A^*=e^{-itK}-X,A'=iKe^{itK},A'(0)=ik$. Let $A^*A=V,U=V^{1/2}$. We consider $f(t)=tr(XU^3)$; then $f'(0)=tr(X(U'U²+UU'U+U²U'))_{|t=0}$. It remains to calculate $U'(0)$. Note that $V(0)=(I-X)^2$ is $>0$ iff $(*)$ $1\notin spectrum(X)$.

Under the condition $(*)$, $U'(0)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-xV^{1/2}}V'(0)e^{-xV^{1/2}}dx$. Clearly $V'(0)=(A'^*A+A^*A')_{|t=0}=-iK(I-X)+(I-X)iK=0$; finally $U'(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! How does the formula come for $U'(0)$? Could you recommend me a good book on matrix calculus?

Comment: For the required formula, cf. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/193905/how-to-calculate-the-square-root-of-matrix-ab-perturbatively/193921#193921 . Yet, the precise formula is useless; indeed $U=g(V)$ implies $U'=Dg_V(V')=0$ if $V'=0$ (recall that $Dg_V$ is linear). About a good book about advanced differential calculus, I do not know.